# Can't connect to MySQL in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, mysql, intellij-idea, jconnect

I have this problem:

[image: image1]

[image: image2]

This issue (cannot find specified file) appeared when I updated IntelliJ IDEA to version 2017.3.2.

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2017.3.2 (Ultimate Edition)
Build #IU-173.4127.27, built on December 25, 2017
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b8 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0
```

All input data is correct. What is the reason?

Comment: What is shown if you click on view?

Comment: @RomanC connection error. It is on second screen.

Comment: I ran into that once or twice and I didn't have the correct JAVA_HOME set after updating. Since your on Windows, have you tried restarting? Also, if you are programming for Android, do you have the correct Android SDK installed?

Comment: @TBridges no, JDK was reinstalled and JAVA_HOME checked.

Answer (score 1):

If you configured data sources from IJ folder then a new version of IJ might contain newer versions of libraries and you should recreate you DS after upgrade.

To make a connection to databases from IJ you need to configure data sources first. A datasource contains a path to the library with drivers needed to make a connection to the server.

You can read [how to connect to databases in IJ](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/connecting-to-a-database.html).

> To be able to work with your database, define it as a data source.
>
> In the lower part of the dialog, within Download missing driver files, click the Download link.
>
> [image]